# A problem on probability concerning distributions of particles

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I saw this problem in *An Introduction to the Theory of Statistics* by *Mood, Graybill, and Boes* (2nd ed.). I am quite intrigued by the problem. Here it is:

> Suppose that a particle is equally likely to release one, two or three
>   other particles and suppose that these second generation particles
>   are, in turn, equally likely to release one, two or three third
>   generation particles. Find the pmf of the number of third generation
>   particles.

I am thinking of doing this by listing all possible outcomes (which I suppose are from 1 to 27), and then manually compute for the probabilities of each. However, I know that it will be very tedious. So I am wondering if there is an easier way for this (perhaps using discrete distributions?). Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a generating function.  For one generation (no pun intended), the generating function is

$$
F(z) = \frac{z+z^2+z^3}{3}
$$

since there is a one-third probability of producing either one ($z$), two ($z^2$), or three ($z^3$) offspring.  To determine the generating function for the grandchildren, we simply write

$$
\begin{align}
F(F(z)) & = \frac{F(z)+[F(z)]^2+[F(z)]^3}{3} \\
        & = \frac{z^9+3z^8+6z^7+10z^6+12z^5+12z^4+16z^3+12z^2+9z}{81}
\end{align}
$$

I didn't do that by hand; I used a symbolic math package.  Anyway, at this point, one can merely read off the probabilities: $1/81$ probability of nine grandchildren, $3/81 = 1/27$ probability of eight grandchildren, etc.

ETA: I noticed that you expected a range of $1$ to $27$ descendants.  That would happen at the fourth generation; for that, you could compute $F(F(F(z)))$.  That yields a big long expression that's a bit too large for this space.  But I can say, for instance, that the most common result is six great-grandchildren, for which the probability is

$$
\frac{142182}{1594323} = \frac{5266}{59049} \doteq 0.089180
$$

Comment: Hi! Thank you for a wonderful solution. I never thought pgf is this useful. Also, thank you for the clarification about the "generations". Yeap, through your explanation, I noticed that "27" is actually part of the next (4th) generation.